# How to reset/restore to original spawn

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to mock spawn process using [mock-spawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-spawn) module. The subsequent test are failing since I am not able to restore the mock.

I tried with `mySpawn.resotre()` but there is no such function. I checked the code still not able to figure it out.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar requirement, this is the comment from mock-spawn contributor

> You can simply require('child_process').spawn if you need the original
>   back. If you have overridden that, you should save the original before
>   and reset the child_process spawn property to the saved original.

Ref: https://github.com/gotwarlost/mock-spawn/issues/13#issuecomment-342589086